# How to define multiple folders for JLink in PacletInfo.wl file?

Tags: packages, java, paclets

I have a paclet info file setup as follows:

```
PacletObject[<|
    ...
    "Extensions" -> {
        ...
        {
            "JLink",
            "Root" -> "Java"
        }
        ...
    }
|>]
```

Now I want to add another folder containing `JAR` files for another application. How do I tell the paclet system to look for `JAR` files in multiple folders under root directory of "Java"? I want to keep files separate for different applications under "Java".

I tried this:

```
PacletObject[<|
    ...
    "Extensions" -> {
        ...
        {
            "JLink",
            "Root" -> {"Java/App1", "Java/Driver/App2"}
        }
        ...
    }
|>]
```

This doesn't work!